# HiveMetaStoreClient thinks Derby but actually Postgres

Tags: hive, cloudera, metastore

I'm trying to connect to a Posgres Hive Metastore through an Oozie Java Action using the code below.

I'm passing the hive-site.xml to the action so it should have all the information it needs.

`HiveMetaStoreClient client = new HiveMetaStoreClient(conf);
log.info("Successfully created the HiveMetaStoreClient");
try {
    log.info(String.format("Loading the partitions for %s.%s", database, table));
    List<Partition> partitions = client.listPartitions(database, table, (short) 200);
    log.info(String.format("Processing %d partitions", partitions.size()));
    for (Partition partition : partitions) {
        StorageDescriptor sd = partition.getSd();
        String location = sd.getLocation();
        String newLocation = location.replace(from, to);
        log.info(String.format("Moving from %s to %s", location, newLocation));
        sd.setLocation(newLocation);
    }
} catch (TException e) {
    logExceptionStack(e);
}`

The log doesn't exactly error, but it suggests that its looking at some other metastore with a DERBY backend;

I'm stumped where to look for the issue and to force `HiveMetaStoreClient` to point to the correct metastore.

`2016-02-08 16:48:05,972 INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] com.xxxxxxx.PartitionMigrator.Program: Attempting to create the HiveMetaStoreClient
  2016-02-08 16:48:06,123 INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] com.xxxxxxx.PartitionMigrator.Program: hiveconf metastoreURI: null
  2016-02-08 16:48:06,194 INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
  2016-02-08 16:48:06,222 INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
  2016-02-08 16:48:06,385 INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] DataNucleus.Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
  2016-02-08 16:48:06,385 INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] DataNucleus.Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
  2016-02-08 16:48:06,506 WARN [uber-SubtaskRunner] DataNucleus.Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
  2016-02-08 16:48:06,840 WARN [uber-SubtaskRunner] DataNucleus.Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
  2016-02-08 16:48:08,339 INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
  2016-02-08 16:48:09,286 INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
  2016-02-08 16:48:09,286 INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
  2016-02-08 16:48:10,400 INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
  2016-02-08 16:48:10,400 INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
  2016-02-08 16:48:10,676 INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql: Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
  2016-02-08 16:48:10,677 INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
  2016-02-08 16:48:10,798 WARN [uber-SubtaskRunner] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.1.0
  2016-02-08 16:48:10,928 WARN [uber-SubtaskRunner] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
  2016-02-08 16:48:11,019 INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added admin role in metastore
  2016-02-08 16:48:11,021 INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added public role in metastore
  2016-02-08 16:48:11,097 INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore: No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
  2016-02-08 16:48:11,193 INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] com.xxxxxxx.PartitionMigrator.Program: Successfully created the HiveMetaStoreClient`

Comment: Could be a CLASSPATH issue -- by default, all `Configuration` constructors for Hadoop projects search for "xxxxx-site.xml" config files in directories present in the CLASSPATH and if they don't find any, they revert silently (!!) to hard-coded "default" values -- e.g. DERBY for Hive Metastore back-end.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *"I'm passing the hive-site.xml to the action "* ? ==> via `<file>` (then it's downloaded in container CWD) or via `<job-xml>` (then it's downloaded *and* somehow merged into Java System Props)

Comment: Did you try to construct your "conf" explicitly from the *hive-site.xml* in CWD, to make sure there is no conflct with another rogue *hive-site.xml* on that node?

Comment: In the action I'm setting the job xml in the action and the workflow to a copy of hive-site.xml stored in HDFS with permissions all good. I've also tried loading it in the code using addResource("hive-site.xml") on the HiveConf object. Silent failure would make sense I guess

Comment: Think you've got me on the right track. Rather than using the job XML, I've added the hive-site.xml as a file in the the action.... its still not working but the error is at least looking more promising

Comment: Also check the Oozie trace in YARN logs (*stdout* for container #2), it's veeeery verbose and includes a list of files/sub-dirs in CWD plus detailed CLASSPATH plus lots of extra stuff.

Comment: All working but I don't understand why hive-site.xml had to added as a workspace file rather than just picking it up using job xml. Wish you'd done this as an answer so I could give you the tick it deserves.

Comment: Could be that `<job-xml>` loads all properties in an *implicit* Configuration object, but when you create your own HiveConf, it starts again from XML files and has no clue about what Oozie has done beforehand.